# Stepping in both WinDbg and Visual Studio causes blue screen

Tags: windows-10, windbg

I'm stuck on this one.  I am able to break in at main, but as soon as I press F10 the system blue screens.

It does it every time.  Same behavior in WinDbg and in Visual Studio.  I uninstalled everything and reinstalled and still the same.

It even happens with the following minimal program:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(int, char*[]) {
    std::puts("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

I can set a break point at std::puts and the debugger stops.  But as soon as I press F10(step) or F5(go) it blue screens -- every time.

It has to be something installed on my system, but I have no idea what that could be.  I've removed VMWare but no change.  The worst part is trying to search for a solution is impossible since "debugger" and "blue screen" occur together like peanut butter and jelly.

This is Windows 1903.

Comment: If you disable the computer's antivirus program, does it still bluescreen?

Comment: still blue screens without a/v

Comment: Perhaps that would have been too easy. You'll have to [diagnose the blue screen problem](https://www.howtogeek.com/163452/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-blue-screen-of-death/).

Comment: That was the right call, the dump had this: PROCESSOR_MAE_INTERNAL_PARITY.  Which led to a BIOS update and I can debug normally again.  I've never seen anything like that, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: And to think just 20 years ago it was always "Are your video drivers up to date?" Now it's gonna be "Is your BIOS(UEFI firmware) up to date?" Glad you got it fixed :) It would be worthwhile stating your motherboard and BIOS versions so Google can index it, in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: I didn't think to write down the previous version of the BIOS, but it's a Gigabyte X299 UD4-CF and the version/date string now shows "American Megatrends Inc. F5, 12/28/2017"

Comment: please  write your solution with your bios details as a self answer and mark it as an answer that way it diesnt get buried